# Cut edge and cut vertices

Tags: graphs

> If $e = \{u, v\}$ is a cut edge with $\deg(u)$ and $\deg(v)$ both at least 2, then $u$ and $v$ are cut vertices.

I want to prove or disprove this statement, but don't know how to proceed. I do know what goes wrong when one of the degrees is smaller than 2.

Comment: What happens to $(u,v)$ when you delete $u$ (or $v$)? What happens to the neighbor of $u$ (resp. $v$) that is not $v$ (resp. $u$)?

Comment: the edge between them disappears and also the edges to their neighbors, but how does that help me proving this statement?

Comment: Let $x$ a the neighbor of $u$ distinct from $v$. Is $x$ connected to $v$ when you delete $(u,v)$? Is $x$ connected to $v$ when you delete $u$?

Comment: yes they are still connected (first case, second case not, since they are not even neighbors)

Comment: If $x$ and $v$ were connected in $G-(u,v)$ as you claim, then let $\pi$ be a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G-e$.  Edge $(u,v)$ cannot be a cut-edge since, in any path in $G$ that uses edge $e=(u,v)$, $e$ can be replaced by  $(u,x) \circ \pi$, where $\circ$ denotes concatenation.

Comment: could you maybe show me how one could prove that? I'm really new to graph theory and just haven't got the grasp for this kind of proofs yes... that would be really helpful and kind so I can understand the concept and can then apply it to other proofs

Comment: My proof until now looks like: there has to be a cycle for degree >=2 so the cut edge must connect two cycles so the vertices that share this cut edge have to be cut vertices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G=(V,E)$. By symmetry it suffices to show that $u$ must be a cut-vertex.

Let $C$ be the set of vertices in the connected component of $G-(u,v)$ containing $u$. Clearly $v \not\in C$.

Let $x$ be a neighbor of $u$ distinct from $v$. Since $(x,u) \in E \setminus \{(u,v)\}$, we must have $x \in C$ and hence $x$ is disconnected from $v$ in $G-(u,v)$.

Since $G-u$ is a subgraph of $G-(u,v)$ containing both $u$ and $v$, $x$ must be disconnected from $v$ in $G-(u,v)$. The claim follows by noticing that $x$ was connected to $v$ in $G$.